# Why can't set mobile hotspot in win10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

Show drivers for wlan:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan show drivers

Interface name: Wi-Fi 2

    Driver                    : Atheros AR9271 Wireless Network Adapter
    Vendor                    : Atheros Communications Inc.
    Provider                  : Atheros Communications Inc.
    Date                      : 6/10/2011
    Version                   : 2.0.0.64
    INF file                  : oem12.inf
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
    802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : No
    Hosted network supported  : Yes
    Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                                WPA-Personal    TKIP
                                WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                                WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                                Vendor defined  TKIP
                                WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                                WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                                WPA-Personal    CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                                Vendor defined  CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
    Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
    Wireless Display Supported: No (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: No)
```

`Hosted network supported  : Yes` ,so hotspot can be created.
Set the network and start it:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myhome key=12345678
The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan start hostednetwork
The hosted network started.
```

Check the status:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan show  hostednetwork    
Hosted network settings
-----------------------
    Mode                   : Allowed
    SSID name              : "myhome"
    Max number of clients  : 100
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status
---------------------
    Status                 : Started
    BSSID                  : 06:1a:8c:30:08:b1
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Channel                : 1
    Number of clients      : 0
```

In win10's mobile hotspot setting:

[image]
Everytime i drag it into to the right in `on` status,it turn back into the left in `off` status automatically.
Why can't share the internet connection with other devices?
And my android phone can connect the `myhome` hotspot,but can't connect the internet!

[image]

How can fix it then?

Comment: Also make sure Wireless is Private and not Public.

Comment: How to make the wireless is private?

Comment: I added a screen shot of how to do this

Comment: `hostednetwork` is a legacy technology that is entirely unrelated to the new Hotspot feature. IIRC you need to set up NAT or routing manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless connection needs to be Private to allow it to be a Hot Spot for other machines.

Use the Settings App, select the wireless setting, and then Private / Public is there.

Please see below:

[image: Set Wireless to Private]

Answer (score 0):

My win10 version is Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448],the answer is a bit of difference from John.
1.In my pc ,can't find the way to make the hotspot private.
2.What i do is simple to set sharing for created hotspot `Local Area Connection*9`.
After running all commands in my post,select as `Contral panel`--`Network and Internet`--`Network Connections`,it will show as:

[image]

The `Local Area Connection*9` is created by my commands.
Now select the `Ethernet` (not other two )
[image]

In Sharing menu, Allow `Local Area Connection*9`  connect `Ethernet`,it is time to connect `myhome` with `12345678` in android phone!